# SQL Multiple Updates vs single Update performance

Tags: sql, sql-update

Assume I have 10,000 rows that need to be updated. What would be faster

```
UPDATE DB.Servers SET Live = 1 where name = 'server1';
UPDATE DB.Servers SET Live = 1 where name = 'server2';
...
UPDATE DB.Servers SET Live = 1 where name = 'server100000';

OR

UPDATE DB.Servers SET Live = 1 where name in ('server1', 'server2'...'server10000');
```

I would assume the second option is faster, but I'm not sure. What worries me is that I don't know if there is a length limit for an SQL stm. What would be recommended in this type of situation?

Thank you

Comment: I would use first approach if I see any change need to be made in the future in update statement as first approach gives flexibility to adjust your query with necessary changes but with second approach, your query need to be generalized

Comment: Which database are you using? sql-server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is supposed to be a declarative language; it does not expect from the user to say "how" to get the result, only "what" the desired result is. So in principal I would use the `in()` construct, as this is the most concise (from a logical viewpoint) way to ask for the results, and let the DBMS (any DBMS!) decide what's best.

Answer (score 6):

**The single `UPDATE` is faster.**

I have tested with MySQL 5.1.73

```
CREATE TABLE test_random (
  val char(40) NOT NULL default '',
  num int NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY val (val)
) TYPE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO test_random (val, num) VALUES
('MXZJBXUGNFOZMMQMYZEMLKZZKTCIGEU',889),
('ZTEBMDHOJGYBYEOPZIIPPJQQOKXMTKU',351),
... [200K records total inserted] ...
('ADLDYZQHDEZMYBHORKGJYMIOVUETQCM',786);
```

Then here is *random-update-single.sql*:

```
UPDATE test_random SET num=1 WHERE val IN (
'PXTUKCZMRFZDTWUPULAPENPNQCSPFQJ',
'GDIMLSCDRSNCMUNUZLQIDFZSEELNZLR',
... [100K records] ...
'ADLDYZQHDEZMYBHORKGJYMIOVUETQCM');
```

And here is *random-update-multiple.sql*:

```
UPDATE test_random SET num=2 WHERE val='PXTUKCZMRFZDTWUPULAPENPNQCSPFQJ';
UPDATE test_random SET num=2 WHERE val='GDIMLSCDRSNCMUNUZLQIDFZSEELNZLR';
... [100K records] ...
UPDATE test_random SET num=2 WHERE val='ADLDYZQHDEZMYBHORKGJYMIOVUETQCM';
```

Here is the result:

```
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-single.sql
0.075u 0.009s 0:01.78 3.9%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-single.sql
0.074u 0.009s 0:01.76 3.9%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-single.sql
0.069u 0.013s 0:01.57 4.4%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

---

```
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-multiple.sql
1.746u 1.515s 0:11.14 29.1%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-multiple.sql
2.183u 2.150s 0:14.83 29.1%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time mysql -uroot test < random-update-multiple.sql
1.961u 1.949s 0:13.96 27.9%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

That is, multiple `UPDATE` turned out to be 5-6 times slower than single `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 2):

The single update will typically be faster since the entire thing would normally be done in a single commit. 10,000 shouldn't be a problem in my experience, but depending on your platform, generating the big SQL like that might not be the best.

What is determining whether a server is going live?  Which platform are you on?  Is it possible you have a table you would send to a procedure as a parameter (SQL Server Table-Valued Parameters) and then use directly in the UPDATE query?

Ultimately, you can only tell with looking at the execution plan and benchmarking yourself.

Comment: I use DB2 for DB. I can script the In() easily in perl. I was just curious about the performance of this because I know both would work, I just wan't sure if I should do it that way (method 2). Thank you guys